# Calling Jquery from external file in Grails

Tags: jquery, grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.5

Having a **jquery** file inside the **assets** folder,and i want to call a function from it in , I used :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${assetPath(src: 'test.js')}">
<g:submitButton class="hr" name="HR Module" onclick="myFunction();"/>
```

but it is not working ,although if i put this function inside  tags in the GSP it works perfectly .

Anything i'm missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: sample image]

Suppose in above snapshot from IDE you have to call `application.js`, then do it like below

```
<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
```

Or if suppose your file is in some subdirectory under assets, then provide relative path. For example, in above snapshot say we have another `application.js` in scripts folder under assets dir. Then,

```
<asset:javascript src="scripts/application.js"/>
```

These are standard tags provided by assets pipeline to access resource.

Last but not least you could similarly access css as well

```
<asset:stylesheet src="bootstrap.css"/>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i did as shown but , still the function not called !!

Comment: seems you are doing something wrong. You should be calling your script before method call. Also, if using chrome, please check for any error on console. The same mentioned above works well in my project.  Can you please check in page source whether the script is added properly or not by clicking on script link and also checking for any javascript errors.

Comment: i'm putting '<asset:javascript src="test.js"/>' in the **head** and i'm calling the function in the **body**

Comment: Did you get the issue @Sherif?

Comment: ya , something wrong in the JQuery code ,  but all done and working fine .. appreciate it .